# Adding the WWW-Authenticate header gives an error

Tags: c#, .net, http, http-authentication, httplistener

I'm trying to configure basic access authorization on my .NET HttpListener but I keep running into the same error. I've tried all the solutions that can be found on this site and many others but with no success.

I need to use admin/admin as username/password for basic authentication. The [wikipedi page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) shows how the header should look, which I followed.

I keep getting the error "The header WWW-Authenticate must be changed with the correct method, parameter:name" there is however no parameter called "name" that must be added, like shown on the wikipedia page. I've ran out of options unfortunately and hope that somebody can help.

My code is as follows

```
private void WebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    if (httpListener == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    HttpListenerContext context = httpListener.EndGetContext(result);

    if (basicAccessAuth)
    {
        HttpListenerRequest Request = context.Request;
        HttpListenerResponse Response = context.Response;

        httpListener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
        NameValueCollection nvCol = new NameValueCollection();
        nvCol.Add("Authorization", "admin:admin");
        httpListener.Realm = "Overflow";

        Request.Headers.Add(nvCol); // error gets thrown here, missing "name" parameter
        Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=");

        HttpListenerBasicIdentity identity = (HttpListenerBasicIdentity)context.User.Identity;
        MessageBox.Show(identity.Name);
    }

    httpListener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(WebRequestCallback), httpListener);

    if (ReceiveWebRequest != null)
    {
        ReceiveWebRequest(context);
    }
    ProcessRequest(context);

}
```

Comment: Sometimes when I'm looking for some sample boilerplate code, I search github for projects that use the code pieces I'm looking for. I scan down through the projects to find someone else who has correctly implemented what I'm struggling with, and sometimes it can provide the answer. For example, https://github.com/s60912frank/BattleMaster/blob/a251894dda76188fe65e46e42b1c4b43686357ae/Client/Assets/SocketIO/WebsocketSharp/Net/HttpListenerContext.cs

Comment: Or perhaps this one? https://github.com/s60912frank/BattleMaster/blob/a251894dda76188fe65e46e42b1c4b43686357ae/Client/Assets/SocketIO/WebsocketSharp/Net/AuthenticationResponse.cs

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @NateW ! Unfortunately I don't think that the WWW-authenticate headers gets used in the examples that you send me.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I don't know enough about http to help you. I was just trying to give you a fresh suggestion.

Comment: no problem @NateW I appreciate the help!

Comment: Look at Roles : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure out my issue. I added the header in the wrong way, it should be Response.AddHeader instead of Response.Headers.Add